# pandas - how to retrieve the index of the minimum and maximum from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to always retrieve the row with index and value out of two dataframes.

These two dataframes have a timeseries index of the same length, moreover they both have 1 single column that contains the value of interest.

So far my approach gives me the min index (could be applied to max as well)

```
pd.concat([df1.col1, df2.col1], axis=1).idxmin()
```

which gives me

```
col1   2022-06-04 22:40:00
col1   2022-06-05 01:50:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then I subset the dataframe which has the minimum:

```
df1.col1['2022-06-04 22:40:00']
```

But this process is manual and I'd like to always retrieve the minimum, and what if the second dataframe contains the lowest value out of the two? How could I make sure I'm getting the lowest other than manually checking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with 4 aggregate functions for get indices and values by `min` and `max`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,6]}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-02',periods=3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,6]}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-02',periods=3))



out = (pd.concat([df1.col1, df2.col1], axis=1, keys=['df1','df2'])
         .agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax', 'min', 'max']))
print (out)
                        df1                  df2
idxmin  2010-01-02 00:00:00  2010-01-04 00:00:00
idxmax  2010-01-04 00:00:00  2010-01-03 00:00:00
min                       1                    6
max                       6                   20


print (out.loc['idxmin', 'df2'])
2010-01-04 00:00:00

print (out.loc['min', 'df2'])
6
```

Comment: The idx line throws an error: ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.

Comment: @Geosphere - ouput are 4 DataFrames?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Geosphere - if input data are `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,6]}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-02',periods=3))` `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[10,20,6]}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-02',periods=3))` what is expected ouput?

Comment: A pandas series with index and value, like a row.
'2010-01-02', 1

Comment: @Geosphere - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add max() command its available in pandas.

PD.COLUMNS.MAX(column name)
same for minimum value.

it will help.